# How to get data-* content when ID is the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, tags

I've created 2 data-* tags. data-category and data-tag. On click of a href tag I want to copy that data-category and data-tag to form inputs. My code is:

```
<div class="multi-dropdown-list-1">
    <ul class="multi-dropdown-list">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="ico-media" data-category="Accommodation" data-tag="Accommodation2" id="industry_url">
                Accommodation
                <i class="socialbakers-icons-before" data-icons-before="&#xe648;"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="ico-media" data-category="Airlines" data-tag="Airline2" id="industry_url">
                Airlines
                <i class="socialbakers-icons-before" data-icons-before="&#xe648;"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="Post" id="industry_form" name="industry_form" method="post" type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">     
  <input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />
  <input id="text_tag_input2" type="text" name="tags2" />
</form>
```

and my Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function() {
    var value = $('#industry_url').attr('data-category');
    var value2 = $('#industry_url').attr('data-tag');
    var input = $('#text_tag_input');
    var input2 = $('#text_tag_input2');
    input.val(value);
    input2.val(value2);
</script>
```

Currently whenever I click on any of the href I get the data-cat and data-tag of the top href no matter which href I click on. How would I get the unique value depending on which one I click?

(I realise that the ID's are the same but I need them to be as the list is auto generated)

Comment: **ID must be unique.**

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is missing here

Comment: try this $(this).data('category'); and $(this).data('tag')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. You can rather use same class.

Also you need to use clicked element context `this` to target it along with `.data()` instead of `.attr()` to get elements data property.

```
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function() {
 var value = $(this).data('category');
 var value2 = $(this).data('tag');
 var input = $('#text_tag_input');
 var input2 = $('#text_tag_input2');
 input.val(value);
 input2.val(value2);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) to target the clicked-on element:

```
<script>
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function() {
var value = $(this).attr('data-category');
var value2 = $(this).attr('data-tag');
var input = $('#text_tag_input');
var input2 = $('#text_tag_input2');
input.val(value);
input2.val(value2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a#industry_url', function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('data-category');
  var value2 = $(this).attr('data-tag');
  var input = $('#text_tag_input');
  var input2 = $('#text_tag_input2');
  input.val(value);
  input2.val(value2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-dropdown-list-1">
    <ul class="multi-dropdown-list">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="ico-media" data-category="Accommodation" data-tag="Accommodation2" id="industry_url">
                Accommodation
                <i class="socialbakers-icons-before" data-icons-before="&#xe648;"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="ico-media" data-category="Airlines" data-tag="Airline2" id="industry_url">
                Airlines
                <i class="socialbakers-icons-before" data-icons-before="&#xe648;"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="Post" id="industry_form" name="industry_form" method="post" type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">     
  <input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />
  <input id="text_tag_input2" type="text" name="tags2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ID`'s wrongly here. `ID` [must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

However you don't strictly need to do another selector in this instance. You can reference the element that was clicked on directly, as it is passed to the click handler as an argument;

```
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function (e) {
  var $target = e.currentTarget;
  var category = $target.data('category');
  var tag = $target.data('tag');
  ...
});
```

Note jQuery also provides a shorthand function [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for accessing the data attributes of an element.